# convert time of format(00:00) to millisecond

Tags: android

I am developing an `Alarm clock` type app which shows notification bar at the time which is set by the user using `Time picker` widget, for this I use Alarm Manager as follows:

```
    TimePicker tm=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    int hour=tm.getHour();
    int min=tm.getMinute();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, my_broadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(),234324243, intent, 0);
        Calendar cSchedStartCal1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    int h=cSchedStartCal1.HOUR;
    int m=cSchedStartCal1.MINUTE;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,X, pendingIntent);
```

I want to know the Value of **X** so to Notify at that time

Comment: X is the time when you want to show the Alarm. Do you want to repeat the alarm everyday?

Comment: Replace **X** with `cSchedStartCal1.getTimeInMillis()` method

Comment: it is not necessary but it  happens then good

Comment: @Mandy8055 cSchedStartCal1.getTimeInMillis() gave the current time in millis but i want the time set by user in timepicker in millis

Comment: Sorry what did that mean? You want that user sets the time in `millis` or something else?

Comment: user set time on Timepicker and we have to convert it to millis so to broadcast it by alarmmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
calendar.setHour(HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.setMinute(MINUTE, minute);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Also, your app won't work properly on android marshmallow and later. You should consider using `AlarmManager` along with `setAlarmClock()` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Answer (score 0):

then try like this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month,day, 
         hour, minute, 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

here set year as current year, current month, current day, selected hour and minute

Comment: please see this for details of timeunit https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: i want to convert the time taken by timepicker to millis

Comment: Timepicker is a view for selecting the time of day, in either 24 hour or AM/PM mode. And to convert time into milisecond you will need date

Comment: data can be taken by system current date